# Display pop up on page load instead of click event

Tags: jquery, popup

My question is simple:
I have this pop up code that I want to load as soon as the page is loaded.
Currently it loads upon clicking.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function(){
//open popup
$("#pop").click(function(){
$("#overlay_form").fadeIn(1000);
positionPopup();
});

//close popup
$("#close").click(function(){
$("#overlay_form").fadeOut(500);
});
});
```

My complete code is located here- `http://jsfiddle.net/VVZch/1/`

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Just keep your popup code outside of click function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//open popup
var popupFun=function(){
$("#overlay_form").fadeIn(1000);
positionPopup();
}
popupFun();
//to add on click event also
$("#pop").click(function(){popupFun()};


//close popup
$("#close").click(function(){
$("#overlay_form").fadeOut(500);
});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load the popup without clicking , why don't you remove the click event

and just write

```
$("#overlay_form").fadeIn(1000); 
positionPopup();
```